# Django FormWizard Filtering ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

here is the code of my forms :

```
class ServiceChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def activated_services(self):
    """
        get the activated services added from the administrator
    """
    all_datas = ()
    data = ()

        services = ServicesActivated.objects.filter(status=1)
        for class_name in services:
            data = (class_name, class_name.name.rsplit('Service', 1)[1])
            all_datas = (data,) + all_datas
        return all_datas


class ProviderForm(ServiceChoiceForm):

    provider = forms.ChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProviderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['provider'].choices = self.activated_services()                

    class Meta:
        model = TriggerService
        fields = ('provider', )


class ConsummerForm(ServiceChoiceForm):

    consummer = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = TriggerService
        fields = ('consummer', )
```

in my `views.py` in the `get_form()`, at step 0 I load the data with my `ProviderForm` like we can see above, then at step 2 i use the following code to load the data in my `ChoiceField` and try to filter the data with the value I use at step 0 :

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    if step == '2':
        data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        consummer = ServicesActivated.objects.filter(status=1)
        consummer = consummer.exclude(name__exact=data['provider'])
        form = ConsummerForm(instance=consummer)
```

but when I access the `ConsummerForm` I get the error :

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

And It looks like that for Django I try to handle multiple Models

So how can i do to filter the datas of my choicefield consumer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
consummer = ServicesActivated.objects.filter(status=1)
consummer = consummer.exclude(name__exact=data['provider'])
form = ConsummerForm(instance=consummer)
```

You are passing a QuerySet to form instead of a model instance:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/